# Keras: methods to enlarge spartial dimension of the layer output blob

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, keras-layer

What methods can be used to enlarge spartial dimension of the layer output blob?

As far as I can see from documentation it can be:

1. [UpSampling2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#upsampling2d) 
     Does it only upsample with power of 2?
     Also it `Repeats the rows and columns of the data by size[0] and size[1] respectively.` and it's not very smart.
2. [Conv2DTranspose](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose)
   Can it have arbitary output size (not power of 2 upsapmple)?

   How bilinear interpolation upscale with arbitary dimensions can be done (it can be Conv2DTranspose with fixed weights?)

   What other options can be used to enlarge spartial dimension of the layer output blob?

Comment: There's no build-in way to do this. If you're using the TF backend, you can use https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images and wrap it in a Keras Lambda layer.

Comment: What about Zeropadding?

Answer (score 10):

Expanding on the [answer from y300](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3427404/y300), here is a complete example of wrapping TensorFlow bilinear image resizing in a Keras Lambda layer:

```python
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Lambda
import tensorflow as tf

def UpSampling2DBilinear(size):
    return Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize_bilinear(x, size, align_corners=True))

upsampler = Sequential([UpSampling2DBilinear((256, 256))])

upsampled = upsampler.predict(images)
```

Note that `align_corners=True` to get similar performance to other bilinear image upsampling algorithms, as described in [this post](https://hackernoon.com/how-tensorflows-tf-image-resize-stole-60-days-of-my-life-aba5eb093f35).

To use bicubic resampling, create a new function and replace `resize_bilinear` with `resize_bicubic`.

For an implementation even more similar to UpSampling2D, try this:

```python
from keras import backend as K

def UpSampling2DBilinear(stride, **kwargs):
    def layer(x):
        input_shape = K.int_shape(x)
        output_shape = (stride * input_shape[1], stride * input_shape[2])
        return tf.image.resize_bilinear(x, output_shape, align_corners=True)
    return Lambda(layer, **kwargs)
```

This will allow you to use `name=''`, `input_shape=''` and other arguments for `Lamba`, and allows you to pass an integer stride/upsample amount.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own resize Layer:

```
from keras import layers, models, utils
from keras.backend import tf as ktf

class Interp(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, new_size, **kwargs):
        self.new_size = new_size
        super(Interp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        super(Interp, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        new_height, new_width = self.new_size
        resized = ktf.image.resize_images(inputs, [new_height, new_width],
                                          align_corners=True)
        return resized

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return tuple([None, self.new_size[0], self.new_size[1], input_shape[3]])

    def get_config(self):
        config = super(Interp, self).get_config()
        config['new_size'] = self.new_size
        return config
```